# Restrict the creation and management of EC2 instances to the IAM user' username

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm currently trying to limit the access of IAM users to EC2 instances. The idea is that a given user can only create (`RunInstances`) and manage (start, stop, terminate, reboot) an EC2 instance that is dedicated to her/him. To summarize the expectations:

- The IAM user can deploy an instance if the instance's name == its user-friendly name
- The IAM user can only manage (start, stop, terminate, reboot) an instance if the instance's name == its user-friendly name

To do so, I tried to implement IAM policies that inspect the `aws:ResourceTag/Name`/`aws:RequestTag/Name` using `Conditions` without much success. The issue is that an IAM user can't deploy an EC2 with a name that should make it work. E.g, an IAM user named `testuser` can't deploy an EC2 instance if its named `testuser`.

What could be wrong with this policy?

Thanks!

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ec2_access" {

  statement {
    sid    = "DescribeAndListInConsole"
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "ec2:Describe*",
      "ec2:GetConsole*",
      "ec2:CreateTags",
      "ec2:*KeyPair*",
      "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
      "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup",
      "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
      "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
      "cloudwatch:*",
    ]
    resources = ["*"]
  }

  statement {
    sid    = "RunEC2Instances"
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "ec2:RunInstances",
    ]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/*",
      "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
      "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
      "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
      "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/ami-*",
      "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:key-pair/*",
      "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*"
    ]
    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "aws:ResourceTag/Name"
      values = [
        "$${aws:username}"
      ]
    }
  }

  statement {
    sid    = "ManageEC2Instance"
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "ec2:StartInstances",
      "ec2:StopInstances",
      "ec2:RebootInstances",
      "ec2:TerminateInstances"
    ]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
    ]
    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "aws:ResourceTag/Name"
      values = [
        "$${aws:username}"
      ]
    }
  }

  statement {
    sid    = "LimitInstanceTypesInUse"
    effect = "Deny"
    actions = [
      "ec2:RunInstances",
    ]
    resources = ["arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"]
    condition {
      test     = "ForAnyValue:StringNotLike"
      variable = "ec2:InstanceType"
      values = [
        "*.nano",
        "*.micro",
        "*.small"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: Here's the encoded authorization failure message that I'm currently getting with the policy used above while trying to deploy a VM named `testuser` with a IAM user of the same name:

```
{
    "allowed": false,
    "explicitDeny": false,
    "matchedStatements": {
      "items": []
    },
    "failures": {
      "items": []
    },
    "context": {
      "principal": {
        "id": "xxxxx",
        "name": "testuser",
        "arn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:user/testuser"
      },
      "action": "ec2:RunInstances",
      "resource": "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-3:xxxxx:instance/*",
      "conditions": {
        "items": [
          {
            "key": "ec2:MetadataHttpPutResponseHopLimit",
            "values": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "value": "1"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "ec2:InstanceMarketType",
            "values": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "value": "on-demand"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "aws:Resource",
            "values": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "value": "instance/*"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "aws:Account",
            "values": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "value": "xxxxx"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "ec2:AvailabilityZone",
            "values": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "value": "eu-west-3a"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "ec2:ebsOptimized",
            "values": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "value": "false"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "ec2:IsLaunchTemplateResource",
            "values": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "value": "false"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "ec2:InstanceType",
            "values": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "value": "t2.micro"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "ec2:RootDeviceType",
            "values": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "value": "ebs"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "aws:Region",
            "values": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "value": "eu-west-3"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "ec2:MetadataHttpEndpoint",
            "values": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "value": "enabled"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "ec2:InstanceMetadataTags",
            "values": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "value": "disabled"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "aws:Service",
            "values": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "value": "ec2"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "ec2:InstanceID",
            "values": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "value": "*"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "ec2:MetadataHttpTokens",
            "values": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "value": "optional"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "aws:Type",
            "values": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "value": "instance"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "ec2:Tenancy",
            "values": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "value": "default"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "ec2:Region",
            "values": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "value": "eu-west-3"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "aws:ARN",
            "values": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "value": "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-3:xxxxxxxxxx:instance/*"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: So what's the issue you're seeing? Users who shouldn't be able to deploy can deploy?

Comment: The other way around, I can't deploy an EC2 with a name that should make it work. Will edit my post, sorry for that!

Comment: check this blog: https://www.cloudkaramchari.com/blog/limit-iam-user-access-to-ec2-instances-in-aws/

Comment: @CloudKaramchari, I wish it was that simple but sadly not... I can't make it work with your solution. Can you?

Answer (score 0):

You will get an "UnauthorizedOperation" error during an EC2 instance launch, which indicates that permissions attached to the AWS IAM role or user trying to perform the operation doesnt have required permissions to launch EC2 instancs. As the error involves an encoded message, you can use AWS CLI to decode the message.

```
aws sts decode-authorization-message --encoded-message encoded-message
```

The decoded message lists the required permissions that are missing from the IAM role or user policy.

You can edit the IAM policy associated with the IAM role or user to add the missing required permissions. To know more about the steps, Kindly [refer](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-not-auth-launch/#:%7E:text=Resolution%201%201.%20Verify%20that%20the%20AWS%20CLI,missing%20required%20permissions%20listed%20in%20the%20preceding%20step.)

In your IAM policy, it does not have permission for Security Groups hence EC2 instance is not getting launched. Kindly find the below policy with the required permissions which will restrict the management of EC2 instances to the IAM username.

```html
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/ami-*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:key-pair/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/Name": "${aws:username}"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/Name": "${aws:username}"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:Describe*",
                "cloudwatch:*",
                "ec2:GetConsole*",
                "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:*KeyPair*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/Name": "${aws:username}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hey @Makendran ! Thanks for having a look! With you solution, I'm still unable to make it run as I would expect. Let say that my IAM user is named `testuser`, I would expect the instance to be deployable via the console by the user in question if it is named `testuser`. Not possible if not. Same for the management.

Comment: I edited my question above with my current policy and the output of the `aws sts decode-authorization-message` !

Comment: In the Sid -> Visualeditor1 policy, Add action "ec2:RunInstances" to your policy in addition to the three actions.

"Action": [
                "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:RunInstances".
                "ec2:StopInstances"
            ],